# Check radio button with Behat

Tags: radio-button, behat, mink

I'm stuck in this problem for 1 hour. It should be not difficult, actually, to check a radio button with Mink. How to do that, I have already found. But it works only when the radio button is inside of form tags. If I have

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input id="payone" type="radio" name="payment[method]" value="payone_today">
            <label for="payone">Vorkasse</label>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

There is no way to check the radio button, or I couldn't find it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

I find that the 'When I select "value" from "name"' form works for selecting radio buttons. Perhaps your code would work with: When I select "payone_today" from "payment[method]".

Comment: This answer worked for me, and is much simpler than adding whole extra methods for something that already exists.

Comment: Also worked for me, but if input element is with "display:none" then its not working.

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar issue and used a similar solution - but there was a twist to my exact requirements that I thought might be of use.

What happens if you have two radio buttons with the same label text?  This is entirely possible when you have multiple radio button groups and the solution above will only find the first button with that label in the DOM - and you might want it to be the second or third.

Providing each radio button group is inside a container then you can start from that container rather than work your way through the entire DOM.

My solution to the original question and to my slightly extended version are both shown below.

```
/**
 * @When /^I check the "([^"]*)" radio button$/
 */
public function iCheckTheRadioButton($labelText) {
    $page = $this->getMainContext()->getSession()->getPage();
    foreach ($page->findAll('css', 'label') as $label) {
        if ( $labelText === $label->getText() ) {
            $radioButton = $page->find('css', '#'.$label->getAttribute('for'));
            $radioButton->click();
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new \Exception("Radio button with label {$labelText} not found");
}

/**
 * @When /^I check the "([^"]*)" radio button in "([^"]*)" button group$/
 */
public function iCheckButtonInGroup($labelText, $groupSelector){
    $page = $this->getMainContext()->getSession()->getPage();
    $group = $page->find('css',$groupSelector);
    foreach ($group->findAll('css', 'label') as $label) {
        if ( $labelText === $label->getText() ) {
            $radioButton = $page->find('css', '#'.$label->getAttribute('for'));
            $radioButton->click();
            return;
        }
    }
    throw new \Exception("Radio button with label {$labelText} not found in group {$groupSelector}");
}
```

Comment: I am trying 2nd example check button in group. I am giving parent id as  groupselector. but its throwing error "call to member function FindAll"

Comment: I'm guessing your group selector doesn't work.  Can you post more details of what the selector is, what the markup looks like.

Comment: This is helpful as I have several pages with multiple 'Yes' and 'No' sets on each page.

Answer (score 1):

If your radio button has a `<label>`, and that label uses the `for` attribute to identify its target, you can use this code:

```php
/**
 * @When /^I select the "([^"]*)" radio button$/
 */
public function iSelectTheRadioButton($labelText)
{
    // Find the label by its text, then use that to get the radio item's ID
    $radioId = null;
    $ctx = $this->getMainContext();

    /** @var $label NodeElement */
    foreach ($ctx->getSession()->getPage()->findAll('css', 'label') as $label) {
        if ($labelText === $label->getText()) {
            if ($label->hasAttribute('for')) {
                $radioId = $label->getAttribute('for');
                break;
            } else {
                throw new \Exception("Radio button's label needs the 'for' attribute to be set");
            }
        }
    }
    if (!$radioId) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Label '$labelText' not found.");
    }

    // Now use the ID to retrieve the button and click it
    /** @var NodeElement $radioButton */
    $radioButton = $ctx->getSession()->getPage()->find('css', "#$radioId");
    if (!$radioButton) {
        throw new \Exception("$labelText radio button not found.");
    }

    $ctx->fillField($radioId, $radioButton->getAttribute('value'));
}
```

I adapted this from the blog post linked to in Nassim's answer - the code there relies on your radio button `<input>` being wrapped in a label, which wasn't possible (well, not easy) in my situation.

Answer (score -1):

I found the easiest code solution was something like this.

```
/**
 * @Given /^I check the "([^"]*)" radio button with "([^"]*)" value$/
 */
public function iCheckTheRadioButtonWithValue($element, $value)
{
  foreach ($this->getMainContext()->getSession()->getPage()->findAll('css', 'input[type="radio"][name="'. $element .'"]') as $radio) {
    if ($radio->getAttribute('value') == $value) {
      $radio->check();
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Calling `check()` on a radio element is the problem here. This code throws the error `cannot tick as it is not a checkbox (radio)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is what I get `You cannot tick "condition" as it is not a checkbox (radio).`